# Creation of a SOAP service possible in micronaut?

Tags: soap, kotlin, micronaut

I want to create a SOAP service in micronaut using kotlin. I can not find information about how to do this. Annotations like @WebService are not being hosted as an endpoint.

I've successfully exposed the result to a rest endpoint.

I found information about how to implement a soap client in micronaut.

I succeeded in publishing the endpoint using [endpoint.publish(..., ...)](https://memorynotfound.com/jax-ws-soap-web-service-example/), but I want to use the built-in netty-server, and perhaps built-in annotations, to prevent having to expose my services in a different class.

Comment: Little late tot the party :D No.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you would use micronaut http client for that. Look at apache axis 2 and see how you can use that.